# Charset detection with UDE and getting the text to string - impact on performance

Tags: c#, encoding

I am curious about one thing. I am using the following code to open the file and read it with the right encoding - UDE is Mozilla Universal Charset Detector 1.1.0. I don't know what the input string file will be, but I can try guessing.

However, I am doing the same thing twice - first I need to create the file stream from the file, as that's what UDE accepts, then I need to get the content into the string to process. I tried getting the file stream to stream reader and then to string, but this messes up the order of the lines.

So, I end up with `File.ReadAllText(sttFile, enc);` and I am wondering  if this could be done better/faster and what would be the impact on performance in case of hundreds of large text files.

```
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(sttFile);
        Ude.CharsetDetector cDet = new Ude.CharsetDetector();
        cDet.Feed(fs);
        cDet.DataEnd();
        Encoding enc = Encoding.UTF8;
        try
        {
            enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(cDet.Charset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to obtain encoding of the file to {0}. Corrupted characters may occur.", cDet.Charset);
        }

        //this messes up the lines order??
        //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs, enc);
        //string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

        string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(sttFile, enc);
```

Any ideas or suggestions welcome, thanks!

Comment: Messes up the order of the lines how?  Maybe the call to `cDet.DataEnd()` reads the stream `fs` and therefore the starting position is off when you use it again?

Comment: Yep, that must have been true. The order of lines appeared random, but when I used fs.Position = 0, the file came out correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the file again will take a negligible amount of time compared to other things. So I wouldn't worry about it. You should aim to write the clearest code unless performance is an actual, measured concern. And in this case, the clearest is `File.ReadAllText`.

If you really wanted to reuse the stream, you would just reset the `fs.Position` to 0.

Finally, you should put a `using` clause around `File.OpenRead`, to guarantee that the file gets closed. Your current code probably leaves it open, unless UDE closes it (I doubt that it does). Specifically:

```
var enc = Encoding.UTF8;
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(sttFile))
{
    ... rest of the code ...
}

string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(sttFile, enc);
```

Comment: Well, performance is kind of important here, so if this would be a matter of 5 or 10% increase in performance, then I'd rather go with the faster option

Comment: @Bartosz it probably saves a fixed amount of time on the order of less than 1 millisecond per invocation, rather than a percentage of the time required to autodetect & read the file.